# Ruby - How do I print HTML attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to build a bootstrap carousel on my page. The carousel needs to look like this, with the first element having an active class.

```
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
```

How do I achieve the same thing in Ruby?  Can I print the data slide number, and the active class from the same statement.

```
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <% @order_items.each_index do |n| %>
    <li data-target="#carousel-order-item" data-slide-to=<%= "#{n}";  (n == 0) ? "class="active"" : '' %>></li>
    <% end %>   
  </ol>
```

Thanks!

Comment: you probably should move the logic into an helper method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want

```
<li data-target="#carousel-order-item" data-slide-to="<%= n.to_s %>" <%= if (n == 0) ? 'class="active"' : '' %> ></li>
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew. The single quotes around the 'class="Active"' is adding double quotes around Active, to make it class=""Active"". So I just have 'class=Active' now and the HTMl appears right. Also, any reason why you have the to_s in there.

Answer (score 2):

Try this and comment back with your results so that I can further assist you.

```
<% @order_items.each_index do |n| %>
  <li data-target="#carousel-order-item" data-slide-to="<%= n %>" 
  <%= "class=\"active\"" if n == 0 %> ></li>
<% end %>
```

This works as such

```
order_items = %w{ mice rice lice }

order_items.each_index do |n| 
  puts n
  puts "class=\"active\"" if (n == 0)
end
```

When `n == 0` then `class="active"` will be output.

Comment: Great, thanks! See my comment to Andrew above, about the double quotes, but other than that, this works.

Comment: @learning_to_swim try the code now. I escaped the dbl quotes. The output should be proper. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Well this is just going to be an array so what about just getting the index of each element? Something like-

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <% @order_items.each do |n| %>
    <li data-target="#carousel-order-item" data-slide-to="<%= n.index %>" class="<%= 'active'if n.index == 0 %>"></li>
    <% end %>   
  </ol>
```